# Function dominated by convex function is eventually convex

Tags: calculus, derivatives, convex-analysis

Suppose that we have a twice-differentiable function $f$ on $x\in [0,\infty)$ such that

1. $f(x)>0$ on $x\in [0,\infty)$  (i.e. strictly positive)
2. $f'(x)<0$ on $x\in [0,\infty)$ (i.e. strictly decreasing)
3. $f^{''}(x) >0$ on $x\in [0,\infty)$  (i.e. strictly convex)
4. $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0$

and we have a twice-differentiable function $g(x)$ such that

1. $f(x)>g(x)>0$ on $x\in [0,\infty)$  (i.e. strictly less then $f(x)$ and strictly positive)
2. $g'(x)<0$ on $x\in [0,\infty)$ (i.e. strictly decreasing)

**Is it true that there exist some $x_0$ such that $g^{''}(x)>0$ for all $x \in [x_0,\infty)$?**

Or in other words does a function dominated by convex function  eventually becomes convex.

As an example of $f(x)$ consider $e^{-x}$ or $\frac{1}{1+x}$.

**Edit** Thanks to the example given @user225318. The above is not true.
What if we add more more assumption that is

3) There exists $x_1$ such that $g^{'}(x) < f^{'}(x)$ for all $x \in [x_1, \infty)$. (i.e. derivative of $g(x)$ is eventually dominted by the derivative of $f(x)$.

**Edit**  assumption 3) makes no sense

Comment: I'm trying hard to even picture an $f(x)$ that even matches your original definition in terms of elementary functions.  Nothing is coming to me.  It seems that if the second derivative is positive, then the first derivative will continuously increase - so it will be tough for it to remain negative.  Same with the fourth condition.  If you have an example, I think that would help.

Comment: What about $\frac{1}{1+x}$ or $e^{-x}$

Comment: About your condition (3), note that $g'(x) < f'(x) < 0$ for all $x\in [x_1,\infty)$ together with $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$ and $g(x) > 0$ implies that $g(x) > f(x)$ on $[x_1,\infty)$, which contradicts your other assumptions. Do you mean that $0 < |g'(x)| < |f'(x)|$? In that case see my comment on my answer below.

Comment: @user225318 but since $f(x)>g(x)$ then $g(x) \to 0$

Comment: $$g(x) = g(x) - g(\infty) = - \int_x^\infty g'(x) \mathrm{d}x > - \int_x^\infty f'(x) \mathrm{d}x = f(x) - f(\infty) = f(x) $$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus. You cannot have $f(x) > g(x)$ **and** $g(x)$ decaying faster than $f(x)$ always.

Comment: I see. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $g(x) = e^{-x} (1/2 + \sin(x) / 3 )$. Clearly on $[0,\infty)$ we have $0 < g(x) < e^{-x} = f(x)$.

$$g'(x) = - e^{-x}(1/2 + \sin(x) / 3) + e^{-x} \cos(x) / 3 = - e^{-x} (1/2 + [\sin(x) - \cos(x)]/3) < 0 $$

here we use that the maximum of $|\sin(x) - \cos(x)|$ is $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2} / 3 < 1/2$.  But

$$ g''(x) = e^{-x} \left[ \frac12 - \frac{2\cos(x)}{3}\right] $$

is not signed. In particular, $g''(2k\pi) < 0$ while $g''((2k+1)\pi) > 0$.

Comment: thanks. really cool example. What if I put one more assumption. That the derivative of $g(x)$ is also dominated by the derivative of $f(x)$? That is for some $x_1$,  $g'(x)<f'(x)$ for all $x\in [x_1,\infty)$.

Comment: In my example above, change $f(x)$ to $f(x) = 10 e^{-x}$. Now $g'(x)$ is dominated by $f'(x)$.

Comment: oh wait, you have $f'(x) < 0$. Do you mean dominated as in $|g'(x)| < |f'(x)|$ or exactly as you wrote $g'(x) < f'(x)$?

Comment: I want $g(x)$ do deacrease faster then $f(x)$. So, $g'(x)<f'(x)$, right?

Comment: That's impossible; it contradicts $0 < g(x) < f(x)$ (by the fundamental theorem of calculus). See my comment on your question.